# I don't have offline access to fb user - should I store friends list in session? RoR, Devise, Omniauth & FBGraph

Tags: devise, omniauth, facebook-access-token, fb-graph

I authenticate a user on my app via facebook. While doing this, I obtain the access token and perform my validation. However, soon after signing in, I will have to present my user with their list of friends. Problem is that the access token has expired by then.

Given that I am using devise, omniauth and fbgraph gems, how could I perform this?

Thoughts:

- Obtain a new access token. How do I do this? Would I have to modify my omniauth_callbacks_controller?
- Should I store the friends list in a session variable?

My omniauth controller:

```
def facebook
  @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

Comment: Access tokens should last for 2 hours or so. Once you get one, take it over the the linter tool and debug it.  Share with us how long it lasts for.

Answer (score 0):

hav a look at this..
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token